# IntelliJ not compiling Java code, no error messages

Tags: java, intellij-idea, compiler-errors, compilation

I'm trying to make a small AI using the helper methods/classes available here: https://github.com/rissole/geniusect-selenium

I have the appropriate libraries and have fixed the few import statements that caused trouble. However, IntelliJ will not compile the Java code, and does not display any warnings or error messages. The out folder wasn't created automatically, and when I did create it, it was left empty after attempting to build. I have set the compiler output to the out folder, attempted to rebuild, and deleted and remade the configuration. What could be the issue?

Comment: Your project is probably misconfigured, see https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/configuring-content-roots.html. Make sure the folder with sources is configured as Source Root (displayed in blue in the Project View).

Comment: Ideally start with something very simple. Just open up IntelliJ and do a "hello world" in java. That should give you a better hang on whats going on.

Comment: sometime Javac compiller is very slow so you can use eclipse compiler which is better